# Clickhouse database is only inserting numbers 0 and dates 1970-01-01

Tags: clickhouse

I created replacing merge table, kafka_table and materialview. I am throwing json into kafka to insert data. But if I select materialview, a row is added in which 0 is written in the number type column, and 1970-01-01  00:00:00 is written in the datetime type.

This is the information in the table
[image]

this is the json:

[image]

I don't know why it writes to the database like that, or if something was done wrong?

Comment: How **exactly** do you insert the data? Also, please share all text content **in text form**

Comment: It seems like the consumer which is reading the json messages from kafka is not able to deserialize json properly since those 0's and 1970 are the default values of those datatypes

Comment: I change date format to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss. But nothing has changed.

Comment: If there was an error during json deserialize. How can I check it?

Comment: The clickhouse.log should print any deserialization errors. Can you provide the create statement use for the clickhouse table? Note that column names are case sensitive. Finally what do you mean "But if I select materialview" ? the materialized views purpose is to trigger on inserts into the Kafka engine and send the blocks to the target table. https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/integrations/kafka/kafka-table-engine

Comment: Thank you, worked!!!. it depends columns was in capital letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure columns are same case per comment above. ClickHouse columns are case sensitive.